# How to get consistent pixel sizes Cordova on all iOS & Android devices

Tags: android, ios, css, cordova, pixel

So I am developing an app and the difference in pixel sizes is pretty big. I have an iPhone 7 and a Motorola Moto G5. I have a video 100px width/height element that looks fine on my iPhone, but far too large on my Moto G5. What is the best way to deal with this?

This is my meta tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">`